# Validate Multiple files in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to allow some certain file types to be uploaded. I wrote the below code for one certain file, it worked.

```
def validate_file_extension(value):
    if not value.name.endswith('.zip'):
       raise ValidationError(u'Error message')
```

but I want to allow more than one files, so I set those files in settings_dev, and wrote the below code, but not working.

```
def validate_file_extension(value):
    for f in settings_dev.TASK_UPLOAD_FILE_TYPES:
        if not value.name.endswith(f):
           raise ValidationError(u'Error message')
```

Settings_dev

```
TASK_UPLOAD_FILE_TYPES=['.pdf','.zip','.docx']
```

Models:

```
up_stuff=models.FileField(upload_to="sellings",validators=[validate_file_extension])
```

how can I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are multiple (different) file types in `TASK_UPLOAD_FILE_TYPES`, the `for` loop will always raise the exception. Because any one of the file types does not match.

You don't need to use `for` because [`str.endswith`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.endswith) accepts a tuple as argument.

```
>>> 'data.docx'.endswith(('.pdf','.zip','.docx'))
True
>>> 'data.py'.endswith(('.pdf','.zip','.docx'))
False
```

---

```
def validate_file_extension(value):
    if not value.name.endswith(tuple(settings_dev.TASK_UPLOAD_FILE_TYPES)):
       raise ValidationError(u'Error message')
```

Comment: Thanks you rock! But do you think accessing files like this is effective? I tried using python magic but having hard time with it on windows, it keeps telling me "Can't find magic files" Any idea?

Comment: @picomon, Alternatively you can define `TASK_UPLOAD_FILE_TYPES` as [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#set). Then in `validate_file_extension` use [`os.path.splitext`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to split extension; `extension in TASK_UPLOAD_FILE_TYPES` will give you same result. This way may be slighly more efficient if there are huge file types.

Comment: python magic is used to determine the kind of files users wants to upload. https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic

Comment: @picomon, How about post another question about python-magic?

Comment: Will do that if the author didn't reply back. Thanks! Will update this if I eventually do.